# Get Windows User Account Name using Java from Server Side

Tags: java, windows, spring-mvc, spring-security, waffle

I am writing Java web application using Spring MVC framework, I hava already done authorization through Windows AD with Spring Security framework. But now, I have to get client's Windows account username, how to do that? I am trying to use WAFFLE but didn't find exactly I am searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
request.getRemoteUser()
```

(returns String of username) or

```
request.getUserPrincipal()
```

(returns Principal object that contains username) should provide you with the username.